# Не получается передать из input в скрытую копию письма массив полей 1С Битрикс

Tags: php, html, битрикс

Не понимаю почему происходят таки странные вещи:
Забираю из textarea введенные через запятую емаилы. Передаю массив в поле "Кому":

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Evgeny@mail.com, Olga@mail.com ) )
```

Все хорошо по тегу #EMAIL# в шаблоне письма в поле "Кому" письма уходят всем.
Но стоит этот тег #EMAIL# переместить в поле скрытой копии и письма перестают уходить вообще на эти адреса.
Почему так происходит?? Насколько я понял что поля "Кому" "Копия" "Скрытая копия" имеют одинаковый формат?

Comment: насколько помню - скрытая копия может быть отправлена только на 1 адрес. Или сторонним отправлять, если нужно именно скрытое или просто в поле "копия" передавать ваш список e-mail. Так же не забывайте что поле Кому должно быть заполнено всегда, потому что не письмо может быть не отправлено. 
Так же можно посмотреть таблицу b_event на предмет того что передается в письме. Если не сложно дополните ответ данными из таблицы

Comment: @Taarim Я вставил несколько адресов через админ шаблон в поле скрытой копии и отработало хорошо. Почему вот мой массив подставленный не работает, вот это загадка. Поле Кому обязательно в форме, его никак не обойдешь и так.

Comment: Попробуйте передать не массив адресов, а строку в это поле. В cevent или через что отправляете. И через implode объедините массив

Comment: @Taarim спасибо попробую. Хотя все равно странно, в Кому можно массив а в Скрытую нельзя. Через Cevent отправляю

Comment: увы это битрикс. Без странностей не обходится